# Angular 4 : "export 'AnimationBuilder' was not found in '@angular/animations'

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-animations

I was using these versions

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "archiver": "^2.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
```

And my application was working perfect.

I tried compile it using `ng build --prod --aot` and got this error :

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module

and by referring this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115649/metadata-version-mismatch-with-angular-4) I downgraded `@angular/animation` version from 5 to 4.
Now I am getting this error even if I am compiling using JIT .

> Module '"C
>   :/Codebase/cdf-onboarding/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported member 'AnimationBuilder'.
>
> Module '"C
>   :/Codebase/cdf-onboarding/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported member 'AnimationFactory'.

Thanks!

Comment: npm i @angular/animations@latest or try and update to the latest version of angular

Comment: @RahulSingh As I mentioned I was already using latest animation module which is version 5

Comment: please update angular versions too

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things, you can try:

1) you should import BrowserAnimationsModule from @angular/platform-browser/animations in your App NgModule.

2) If you import any animations services or tools from @angular/core, you should import them from @angular/animations.

3) please update angular versions too.