# Failing to start node application with error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am seeing an error when I start to run my node application.

Error says "ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module ../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3"

Full error trace is:

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module
>   D:/MyProj/Client/node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/index.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   D:/MyProj/Client/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   D:/MyProj/Client/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   D:/MyProj/Client/src/app/app.module.ts webpack: Failed to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error

Probably in your package.json you have the following:

`"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^<VERSION_HERE>"`

The problem is with the dependecies versions, so you can just update everthing to the last version, there is a topic in stackoverflow already: [Metadata version mismatch with Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47115649/metadata-version-mismatch-with-angular-4)

Or in my case that I couldn't just update all packages,I did the following:

I removed the package, also removed the `^` signal before the version number and then ran `npm i` again.

After this the app worked properly.